# Adding eventListener to several items in Angular

Tags: angular, addeventlistener

I add some HTML to the DOM dynamically. There are several hyperlinks with class `someClass` and different ids. And after I add them to template I add event listener to them so when I click them id is logging.

```js
this.HTMLdiv = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.HtmlString);
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.someClass').addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.path[1].id));
```

Problem is that this event listener is added only to first element. 
How can I add it to all elements with class `someClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function. Try the following

```js
this.HTMLdiv = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.HtmlString);
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
const elements = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.someClass');
elements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.path[1].id)));
```

Comment: That's the injected `ElementRef`. I've modified the answer.